# recall session variable in loop

Tags: php, forms, session

I'm working on generating an html form with a loop, where the "quan" is a quantity. I would like to recall the session variables for cases when a form is submitted, user taken to confirmation page, and returns to the form to adjust something (typo in the entry, e.g.). I haven't been able to locate help for this scenario. Here's what I've tried.

```
for($i = 1; $i<= $_SESSION['quan']; $i++) 
{
    echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"nam_" . $i . "\" size=\"35\" value=\""; 
    if (array_key_exists($_SESSION['nam_$i']) { echo $_SESSION['nam_$i']; };
    echo "\" /><br />";
}
```

This generates a series of Post variables (e.g. `$_POST['nam_1']`, `$_POST['nam_2']`, etc.) depending on the quantity ordered.  I convert the Post variables to Session variables w/ another loop when processing the form; and in the if statement I am trying to recall the session variable entered by the user if they need to return to the form to correct something.

Obviously the session value `nam_$i` isn't the right way to do this.

I've toyed with variable variables without success. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You must use `"nam_$i"`, with double quotes in order to the `$i` variable being replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Bob,

It makes your code easier to read and therefore debug if you use a different text delimiter for your `echo` than you are going to use for your `html` also you dont have to add all those escape `\` chars that obsquire whats going on i.e. using

```
echo ' ';
```

will allow you to use the doublequote `"` for html. so

```
for($i = 1; $i<= $_SESSION['quan']; $i++) 
{
    echo '<input type="text" name="nam_' . $i . '" size="35" value="'; 
    if (array_key_exists($_SESSION["nam_$i"]) { 
       echo $_SESSION["nam_$i"]; 
    };
    echo '"/><br />';
}
```

Is a whole lot easier to read and debug.